# .NET MVC 4 : How to set a Partial View shared in multiple Views of different Controllers

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, submenu, controllers

Describing my problem with a school example; 
Say there is a Main Menu in `_Layout.chtml` with links of few classes, i.e. `Class 1, Class 2, Class 3`,... Each link shows a list of students in a `Grid` and each `Row` has some `Edit` link. That link lands us on `Edit` screen for `Student` records.

Now Student properties to be edited are categorized in multiple sections i.e. `Personal, Educational, Sports, Transport`. So there need to a `Menu` to be displayed on left column for each category of `Student` properties. Each category has its own `Controller`, `Service` & `Repository`. So the `Link`s in the `Menu` need to send `Student ID` to the  respective `Controller`, So it can fetch & create the specific properties `Model` of particular `Student` and send to `View`.

I wanted to be guided for how to put that `Menu`. Though I guess I am correct when written it in `Partial View` & included in each `View` of property set.

Problem is that the `Link` doesn't work when `Controller` name is added as below:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Sports Properties", "EditSportsProps", "SportsProperties", new {ID = Model.ID})
```

But works when `Controller` name is not added as below:

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Sports Properties", "EditSportsProps", new {ID = Model.ID})
```

Hence I am narrowed to put all functionality in same controller.

- Can't I link to different `Controller`s from a `Partial View`?
- Note that `Student ID` is required throughout, Is there a way to fetch it from route URL "`ControllerName/ActionName/Id`" in `Controller`? as `ID` is there in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no overload for `ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object)`

You can use overload, [`LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object, Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Thus change your code as, pass `null` for HTML attributes

```
@Html.ActionLink("Sports Properties", 
     "EditSportsProps", 
     "SportsProperties", 
     new {ID = Model.ID}, null)
```

For more info visit [LinkExtensions.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Note: When you are not putting controller name then it works because you are using `ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, Object)` overload